# Ubuntu on new SONY Vaio laptop SVF142C29M

Tags: sound, vaio, sony

I have installed on my son's new laptop SONY Vaio laptop SVF142C29M (instead of Windows 8) and we are very pleased. Congratulations to all who develop this excellent OS.My son loves it!

However, there is a problem with audio support on this machine. Playback works via the headphone socket, but not via the internal speakers. It's easy to work around this. But the microphone is not supported and this represents a serious drawback.

I am a LINUX neophyte. I have been as sophisticated as trying "sudo also force-reload" in the terminal. But that's about as sophisticated as I can get!

Any help would be appreciated or advice on whether I should log this as a bug and wait for a later release to resolve this.

Best wishes,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Kubuntu 12.04 for a friend on this computer and the speaker works correctly.
Perhaps it's because I've installed a 3.11 kernel via:

```
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy
```

And I had to also install `bcmwl-kernel-source` for the BCM43142 wireless.
Also just for your information, when you have an issue with hardware, people will always you ask you for your Ubuntu version, kernel version, lscpi .
Here is mine:

```
guy@guy-SVF1421C5E:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
guy@guy-SVF1421C5E:~$ uname -r
3.11.0-15-generic
guy@guy-SVF1421C5E:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
guy@guy-SVF1421C5E:~$
```